# Grails params.list() does not work

Tags: grails

I pass a series of id parameters in the query part of the uri

```
 ...?id=12&id=16&id=34
```

This comes into the grails controller and is organized by grails into a list

```
id:[12,16,34]
```

but the property is still treated as a string by groovy, so it means this

```
id:"[12,16,34]"
```

The [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#typeConvertershttp://) advises that if only one is passed then grails won't form a list, so to always use the params.list() method to ensure you get a list

```
def ids=params.list('id');
```

But doing that gives me

```
[ "[12,16,34]" ]
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get groovy to treat the property as a list once grails as automatically organizes it as a list.

Comment: the field looks correct, maybe this relates to the inner working of grails and the params id. Try using fid or something else to see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send params with **POST** method and get them by **request.JSON**
or you can split it and assign it to a list.
As I know and experience **params** only returns string.

```
params.id.toString().split('\\[')[1].split(']')[0]
```